# Expectation value of a balls problem

Tags: probability, expectation

> Suppose person A chooses randomly 3 balls from a basket which has 10
>   balls (when the balls are numbered! which means different from each
>   other and uniformly distributed). Afterwards person A returns the balls and person B chooses 3
>   balls randomly and independently  from the same basket.
>
> a) What is is the expectation value of the balls which were chosen by
>   both of them (chosen twice).
>
> b) What is the expectation value of the number of balls chosen once from one of the persons?

I assumed $p(1)=p(2)=...=p(10)= \frac{1}{10}$. How can the answer be independent from parameters, when the expectation value depends on  random variable? Cause let's assume person A picked 3 balls (probability of 3/10), shouldn't the answer include the random variable in order to compare the two?what am is missing?am i supposed to count every possible way it happens ?

Answer (score 2):

a) Any given ball is chosen by both A and B with probability ${3\over10}\cdot{3\over10}$. The expected number of balls to be chosen twice therefore is $10\cdot{9\over100}=0.9$.

b) Any given ball is chosen by A, but not by B, with probability ${3\over10}\cdot{7\over10}$, and with the same probability it is chosen by B, but not by A. The expected number of balls to be chosen exactly once therefore is $10\cdot2\cdot{21\over100}=4.2$.